# Display Scaling in Windows Remote Desktop Connection

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, scaling

I constantly RDP into different servers on our network. Sometimes I want to go full screen, but sometimes I want to specify the resolution. I do both of these through Microsoft's Remote Desktop Connection GUI on Windows. But I want the screen to scale, and there's no option in the GUI to do this.

The official Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection program for OS X has an option to do scaling. You just do View -> Fit to Window. Is there some similar option that I can do for the Windows RDC program? Or is there a 3rd party RDP client that can do this?

Comment: I don't know how you can specify this manually - there probably is a hidden setting that you can put in the .RDP file (it's a text file). Shopping questions are off-topic here (asking for alternative software), but I'll mention RoylaTS as we use it at work - it supports scaling.

Comment: I use RoyalTS as well. It might be a bit of overkill for a single user connecting to one or two remote computers, but it would definitely do the trick.